Handle sparse data in Snowflake
I have a loosely structured data(json) incoming from a source landing intno Snowflake stage. The structure of json(# of KV pairs) are not consistent across files i.e. one file can come up with 5 kv and another one can come up with 10.
How to handle such data in Snowflake if I plan to create wide table structure where each row represents data from a Json payload. If it was in parquet, it would be a sparse table with column values being null values when they are missing from the source.
How does Snowflake handle such inputs. Does it create sparse tables as well, and can you also advice on the schema evolution. Any gotchas as # of columns are updated with each payload.

You can load the data as json into variant columns (and subsequently query/process it) or you can choose to convert it into a more relational structure as you load it into a table. I’m not sure I understand your question as Snowflake doesn’t “handle such inputs” or “create sparse tables” - you decide what you want to do with your data and write the necessary SQL commands to achieve that result. If you update your question with sample source data and the table structure you want to end up with then someone can probably help, if that’s what you’re asking?

Snowflake doesn't create sparse tables as such, but when you load JSON into a table and flatten it, a missing attribute will load as null, which I think is what you were asking.
